# How can i get parent page name in the user control page using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using user control in many pages. I want to find the parent page name in the user control page using javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this in ascx:

```
<script language="javascript">
  var pageName = "<%= System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Page.Request.Path) %>";
  alert(pageName);
</script>
```